# Why would Solr report an unknown field 'pubdate' when using standard SI4T?

Tags: si4t

I have set up SI4T using the unmodified template building blocks for adding indexing data. In the template builder I can see the following index data.

```
<indexdata>
    <url>/index.aspx</url>
    <title>Home</title>
    <publicationid>23</publicationid>
    <schemaid>1511</schemaid>
    <itemtype>64</itemtype>
    <parentsgid>6</parentsgid>
    <sgid>6</sgid>
    <type>0</type>
    <body>....some body content here.... </body>
    <custom/>
</indexdata>
```

However, when publishing, and thereby attempting to save the indexing record to Solr, it complains about `unknown field 'pubdate'`

```
DEBUG wire - << "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request[\r][\n]"
DEBUG wire - << "Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1[\r][\n]"
DEBUG wire - << "Content-Type: application/octet-stream[\r][\n]"
DEBUG wire - << "Content-Length: 111[\r][\n]"
DEBUG wire - << "Date: Fri, 29 Nov 2013 14:45:54 GMT[\r][\n]"
DEBUG wire - << "Connection: close[\r][\n]"
DEBUG wire - << "[\r][\n]"
DEBUG DefaultClientConnection - Receiving response: HTTP/1.1     400 Bad Request
DEBUG headers - << HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
DEBUG headers - << Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
DEBUG headers - << Content-Type: application/octet-stream
DEBUG headers - << Content-Length: 111
DEBUG headers - << Date: Fri, 29 Nov 2013 14:45:54 GMT
DEBUG headers - << Connection: close
DEBUG wire - << "[0x2][0xa2][0xe0].responseHeader[0xa2] [0xe0]&statusP[0x19][0xe0]%QTimeA[0xe0]%error[0xa2][0xe0]#msg?[0x14]
             ERROR: [doc=tcm:23-1956-64] unknown field 'pubdate'[0xe0]$codeP[0x19]"
DEBUG DefaultClientConnection - Connection 0.0.0.0:55800<->192.168.1.252:8080 closed
```

Where might the pubdate field come from? Would it make sense to add this to the solr schema? (But then, maybe I'd need to add all the fields that are in the indexdata). Any other suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Can you post your schema.xml? Or at least the relevant parts?

Comment: I have the solr example schema in place. I was looking in the SI4T documentation for any mention that you have to customise the schema, but didn't see anything. Anyway - schema.xml has no mention of 'pubdate'. But then nor does it mention (for example) 'parentsgid'.

Comment: You'll have to use the SI4T example schema, which was pretty undocumented until now. I've updated SI4T's docs and posted a short explanation as answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SI4T requires a couple of fields to be configured in Solr's schema.xml in order index content coming from the Tridion CM and the SI4T TBB:

**Fields that always need to be present**:

- id : the unique id of the individual item
- url : the url of the published item
- pubdate: the last publish date of the item

**Additional fields coming from the SI4T TBB**

Then, a couple of additional fields will need to be configured, as seen in the XML you post.

**Custom Fields**

If you change the default TBB to for instance add custom fields, you will also need to define  those in schema.xml.

**Binary indexing**

If you want to index binaries like pdf's or word documents, you will also need configure this separately.

I have created an [example schema.xml](https://github.com/SI4T/Solr/wiki/Solr-Schema-Configuration) with further explanation. The example schema.xml is the minimum configuration you need in order to properly index the XML above. From this, you can create or change schema.xml according to your further Solr needs.

Comment: Couple of small updates. I needed to remove a duplication definition of "field name='type'" and also add _version_ and its fieldType.

Comment: Also got: "multiple values encountered for non multiValued field sgid:"... changed it to multi-valued in the schema. Looks like there are more similar issues, but I'm starting to get the hang of it now. :-)

Comment: Thanks for finding that out Dominic. The example maybe was a bit too hastily written and I'll update it asap. But at least you're getting the hang of it. :)